# Make clang-format break lines before a single-statement block with no braces

Tags: c, clang-format

I'm getting something like this:

```
if (!file) return;

for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); ++i) positions[i] = m * positions[i];
```

But I want this:

```
if (!file) 
    return;

for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); ++i) 
    positions[i] = m * positions[i];
```

Comment: What have you tried? How did your attempt work, or not work? And please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I set `AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine` to `false` but it has no effect. I guess it is has to do with the fact of not having braces.

Comment: If you assume this, why don't you check it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this command to break that code into separate lines

```
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine : Never
```

After adding this code to your `.clangformat` file output look like this

```
if (!file) 
    return;

for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); ++i) 
    positions[i] = m * positions[i];
```

[Source](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)